# Though I have a record in database, it's giving "Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound"

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Though I have the record with id 13163 (`db.locations.find({_id: 13163})`), it's giving me error:

**Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound in LocationsController#show**

> Problem: Document(s) not found for class Location with id(s) 13163.
>   Summary: When calling Location.find with an id or array of ids, each
>   parameter must match a document in the database or this error will be
>   raised. The search was for the id(s): 13163 ... (1 total) and the
>   following ids were not found: 13163. Resolution: Search for an id that
>   is in the database or set the Mongoid.raise_not_found_error
>   configuration option to false, which will cause a nil to be returned
>   instead of raising this error when searching for a single id, or only
>   the matched documents when searching for multiples.

```
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_location
  @location = Location.find(params[:id])
end
```

**locations_controller.rb:**

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_location, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /locations
  # GET /locations.json
  def index
    @locations = Location.all
  end

  # GET /locations/1
  # GET /locations/1.json
  def show
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_location
      @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def location_params
      params.require(:location).permit(:loc_name_en, :loc_name_jp, :channel)
    end
end
```

Setting up the option `raise_not_found_error: false` is not the case as I do have a document in database.

---

**SOLUTION:**

Big thanks to [@mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) for giving me a hint.

The problem can be solved in 2 ways:

1. Declare `field :_id, type: Integer` in the model `location.rb`
2. Or converting the passing parameter to Integer like `Location.find(params[:id].to_i)` in `locations_controller.rb` as shown below in the **@mu is too short**'s answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd guess that you have a type problem. You say that this:

```
db.locations.find({_id: 13163})
```

finds the document in the MongoDB shell. That means that you have a document in the `locations` collection whose `_id` is the *number* `13163`. If you used the string `'13163`':

```
db.locations.find({_id: '13163'})
```

you won't find your document. The value in `params[:id]` is probably a string so you're saying:

```
Location.find('13163')
```

when you want to say:

```
Location.find(13163)
```

If the `_id` really is a number then you'll need to make sure you call `find` with a number:

```
Location.find(params[:id].to_i)
```

You're probably being confused because sometimes Mongoid will convert between `String`s and `Moped::BSON::ObjectId`s (and sometimes it won't) so if your `_id` is the usual ObjectId you can say:

```
Model.find('5016cd8b30f1b95cb300004d')
```

and Mongoid will convert that string to an ObjectId for you. Mongoid won't convert a `String` to a number for you, you have to do that yourself.

Comment: Another solution is to declare the type of field in the model *location.rb*: `field :_id, type: Integer`

Comment: @oscar: Right, I didn't even think of that. You could put that down as an answer, it is probably more useful than having to `to_i` all over the place.